# Any reason to not have unsigned id?

Tags: mysql

I know it's silly to worry about running out of IDs, but it still bothers me, so for just piece of mind, would using unsigned int's have any draw backs? Since it's an ID, the loss of negative numbers isn't an issue.

Comment: *Since it's an ID, the loss of negative numbers isn't an issue.* Implying things like `-4` aren't identifiers.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: No; implying that there is no _need_ to allow `-4` as an identifier.

Comment: I have never used negative numbers as IDs, since I always seen that as poor design, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Negative IDs have their uses. In certain circumstances it is useful to generate mutually exclusive identifiers between two servers. You can do autoincrement starting at 1 and incrementing by 1 and -1 and incrementing by -1. You can also do odd/even (start at 1 or 2 and increment by 2).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should pretty much always use unsigned auto increments as your id, if the database provides that as a type.

No drawbacks to worry about.

Ids serve two main purposes:

- uniquely identify objects
- record logical time.

Both of these are satisfied with unsigned ints.

In some rare cases using distributed workloads, uuid or something similar might be preferred, but for general use, autoincremented unsigned integers are fine.

note: some databases don't have support for unsigned integer type (e.g. Redshift). Also, when designing a new table, check the maximum value that an (unsigned) integer can store.

Comment: @EJP I'm not the one who downvoted this, but my guess would be that it was either because of the "always use unsigned auto increments as your id" (as in, the "artificial vs. natural primary key" argument) or the "record logical time" (because it's not always guaranteed that you'll get increasing values - for example, it used to be the case that AUTO_INCREMENT columns in MyISAM could wrap around and start re-using deleted id's. In other words, don't use them for that unless you *know* your database makes the guarantees you are relying on).